# dbAdmin user can not execute list command on MongoDB 3

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a new Database called meanapp.and I add a user meanUser for readWrite role.

When I connect to the mongo DB via mongoose it connects but I got Error as

`{ MongoError: not authorized on meanapp to execute command { listIndexes:"jobs", cursor:{}}`

So , I tried to grant dbAdmin role to meanUser by executing

`db.grantRolesToUser('meanUser',[{role:"dbAdmin", db: "meanapp" }] )`

And tried restarting mongo deamon.

And db.getUser('meanUser') shows the dbAdmin role for that user.

Still same error.

Could any one faced this issue or I am missing something?

I refered mongo docs also I could get an idea of this issue.

Thanks for your effort.

Comment: did you try db.auth('username','password') before running that first command?

Comment: Sorry,I should be more clearly. I have this issue while using mongoose.